# Cannot Set Dynamic TableView Row Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set dynamic row height in TableView. But unfortunately is not working.

The only thing is working is to set the `heightForRowAt indexPath` to a constant number.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 470 //or any other number
}
```

If I delete this function, or try to set it to automatic the cell will not show at all. Something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I also tried to use:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension //Tried even with a number
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

But seems nothing to work besides using a constant height in `heightForRowAt indexPath` function. Which is not what I want, I want cell to be expanded based on content inside the cell.

I also tried to set height in `heightForRowAt indexPath` function to automatic but set a fixed height on constraints in the content of the cell xib file, still same (I did just to see what happens). So seems, something is wrong around this function.

Note:
My TableView and UITableViewCell are divided in a `storyboard` and a `xib` files.

Comment: Show how you have your "cell content" constrained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: You need to provide enough internal constraints to determine the size of the cell without an explicit value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the dynamic tableview row height, you must use autolayout.

Please set the constraint on the UI components in the cell as shown in the image below.

[image]

I used UILabel as sample code. For UILabel, be sure to set Lines to 0.

[image]

Here is the sample code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stringArr = ["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stringArr.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as? TestCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        cell.label.text = stringArr[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

- You need to register the cell in the tableview.

tableView.register(UINib(nibName: “YourCellNibName”, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: “YourCellReuseIdentifier”)

Comment: I did like this, and the cell is not showing at all.

Comment: I updated my question, adding a note.

Note: My TableView and UITableViewCell are divided in a storyboard and a xib files.

Comment: Did you register the cell in the tableview? If you have not registered, please register as follows:


//In viewDidLoad//

tableView.register(UINib(nibName: “YourCellNibName”, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: “YourCellReuseIdentifier”)

Comment: Yep I did, and cell is showing when I set a fixed height in `heightForRowAt indexPath` function. No matter what, I do, when set to automatic or I delete the function, in those cases cell is not showing. I also tried to set it to automatic but set a fixed height on constraints in the content of the cell xib file. Still same.

Comment: Ok, found the solution. In `cellForRowAt indexPath` function the previous dev in return used not the `cell` but `UITableViewCell`. I didn't notice that, after seeing that I fixed.

I'll mark this answer as correct, cause you already wrote it in your answer.